# Hide WPF Window Until Fully Loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, loading, splash-screen

For my WPF application, I am storing several user settings like window position, window state, and whether or not to display a welcome dialog.  The problem is that while everything is loading up, I see a lot of flashing and flickering as the windows are loaded in, and then more flickering when the window is maximized after reading in the settings.

I am already using the built-in WPF PNG splash screen functionality, but is there a way to completely hide the rendering of all windows until everything is fully loaded in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit the Application.xaml, remove the StartUpUri, instead set the StartUp event handler.
In Application.xaml.cs, edit the startup event handler to display the splashscreen, load your resources, create everything, then create the main window and show it.

```
<Application
    ...
    StartUp="OnStartUp"
    />
```

And:

```
private void OnStartUp(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var settings = LoadSettingsFrom... // Call your implementation of load user settings

    // Example only, in real app do this if's section on a different thread
    if (settings.doShowSplashScreen)
    {
        var splashScreen = new SplashScreen();
        splashScreen.Show();
    }

    // Load and create stuff (resources, databases, main classes, ...)

    var mainWindow = new mainWindow();
    mainWindow.ApplySettings(settings); // Call your implementation of apply settings

    if (doShowSplashScreen)
    {
        // send close signal to splash screen's thread
    }

    mainWindow.Show(); // Show the main window
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. The built-in splash screen functionality is set using the SplashScreen Build Action on an image resource. This built-in splash screen is automatically loaded before the Startup event is thrown. In the above code a new instance is being created. What about the automatic one - how do you turn it off? Also, doSplashScreen is referenced above. Where is that defined? Note: I am using VB.NET.

Comment: I did not assume any built-in splash screen is used (functionality 1. added in WPF 3.5 SP1). Setting build action on an image to SplashScreen gives you limited functionality, to disable it, just do not set any images' build action to SplashScreen. doSplashScreen is pseudo-code - it can be any configuration based check (e.g. user preferences).

Comment: OK, thanks. I was confused because the original questions states "I am already using the built-in WPF PNG splash screen functionality". Further confusion was your choice of names - the built-in WPF splash screen is also a class called SplashScreen. Perhaps you should be more explicit about this in your answer (or use a different name). Also, it would be nice to show why your solution better than the built-in.

Comment: It enables displaying the splash screen first, loading everything else, then displaying the main window. Also, your custom splash screen can contain any custom logic.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the windows WindowState to Minimized, then handle the ContentRendered event and set the WindowState to Normal or Maximized.

Comment: Simplest way, thanks!  I used the Window_Loaded event instead, which is where I do all my app initialization.  When that's done, set WindowState and good to go.

Comment: Excellent job. Simple but great. I additionally add built-in splash screen.

Comment: Easy approach! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are functions , BeginInit and EndInit, if you change properties inside these functions like..

```
BeginInit();
...
... // Do your code Initialization here...
...
EndInit();
```

then your window will not render until the EndInit() is called, it will not flicker.

Comment: this causes it to crash

Answer (score 0):

When does this loading occur?  Code executed in the main `Window`'s constructor should execute before the window is shown; if you load any required resources there, you should not see any flickering.